# RXSwift with one time subscriber

Tags: swift, rx-swift, subscriber

I want to subscribe to an observable, but right after the first element, I want to dispose the subscriber.

Is there some default way for that?

If not, how would you solve this?
I cannot change the observable, by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just use take operator :)

```
yourObservable.take(1).subscribe(....
```

Comment: Thank you :) but is `take` also disposing it? Because I need to call the cancel code of the `Cancelable`...

Comment: @ArturHellmann yes, it is disposing. After fist "onNext" you will get "onComplete". Every onComplete disposing subscription.